# How to print out a pdf document stored on local drive in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf

I have a PDF file that I have generated on a back-end flask server to save directly to the vue.js folder (src/assets/pdf folder).

Currently, I am unable to figure out how to invoke the print dialog to print out this PDF file. Almost every single solution online to print something using code involves printing the literal page using `window.print()`.

Additionally, I am at the moment using Vue-PDF to print out the document but it is very buggy and the text comes as boxes (Photo attached for reference).

How can I custom code a button to print out this PDF document that is stored on the locally accessible files and still keep the file intact while printing? I am open to both Vue solutions or even Flask(Python) solutions

[Buggy/Broken Printing of PDF document] https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Zl3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I realized that maybe it didn't have to be a Vue.js specific answer and looked for HTML solutions.

`<embed>` and `<iframe>` are pretty decent solutions.